# SQL...updating product prices but keeping previous values

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a table full of products including price, name, date and ID (PK)

I am in need to update the records when there is a price change (Web scraping script), how would i go about this so that a new row is NOT inserted, rather the price and date are updated.....but the previous values need to remain in the DB....so that when i when i go

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id ='27'";
```

Output wanted:

```
$400  12.4.2013
$314  22.4.2013
$250  12.4.2013
```

The product will be then displayed with all the updated values since the first price was downloaded, effectively it will be a history of the prices for the item...

the actual results i want to achieve would hopefully be

History for "Product 27" is:

To give more context, when i run my script...   ./script.php update
all the new data should be inserted or updated....but old values remain
im not too sure how i should approach this....please provide me with some guidance or assistance

Comment: If you are wanting to keep a history of your old prices then you will most likely have to insert a new row for each updated date and price. There isn't really any other way that I can think of.

Comment: You can separately maintain a log table for the changes. Then you can extract all the change history form the log table.

Comment: Well, you NEED to insert a new row for this. Actually, you could insert only one row for each product and have the history in a serialized array if you really need it, but it's a bad, bad practice and you'll be hated by every cool kid that touches your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the old values I would suggest saving them in a seperate table and to use the `INSERT` statement. You are always adding a new row, so you can not bypass an `insert` or `select into` or similar statement.

Table structure:

```
Items
------------------------------
Id          primarykey
Name

Price
------------------------------
Id          primarykey autoincrement
ItemId      index
AddDate     index
Price
```

Now when you scrape the web you will just insert the new price in the `Price` table. If you want to select all the prices for an item you can use

```
SELECT  Items.Id
       ,Items.Name
       ,Price.Price
       ,Price.AddDate
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Price
ON Items.Id=Price.ItemId
WHERE Items.Id='27'
ORDER BY Items.Name ASC, Price.AddDate ASC
```

And if you just want the latest or current price, you can use

```
SELECT  Items.Id
       ,Items.Name
       ,P1.Price
       ,P1.AddDate
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Price P1
ON Items.Id=Price.ItemId
LEFT JOIN Price P2
ON P1.ItemId=P2.ItemId
AND P1.Id<P2.Id

WHERE Items.Id='27'
AND P2.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: this should work, but my issue there is the only ID i use one from SQL which is a pk or auto increment, so when i run an update or insert a new run of prices for the products....

Comment: how will i know how to insert the new price so it relates to the previous product

Comment: You can still use the same ID you were using now. Only previously you would have something like `UPDATE items SET Price='$100' WHERE Id='YOURID'` and now you will use `INSERT INTO Price (ItemId, Price) VALUES ('YOURID', '$100')`

Comment: but each product does not come with an id..this ID was made via just the original table having a PK...that is the idea each product had...

Comment: Can you show the query how you would UPDATE it without keeping the old data? As one way or the other, you need to be able to retrieve the old PK from the Items table in order to keep a history.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to go about this while keeping a tidy database with easily maintainable and readable data would be to take what @KishorSubedi said in the comment and create a log table.

When you update your price in your Products Table, store the old price, along with its date and ID in the Log Table then when you need to look up all the records for that product you can JOIN the Log Table in your query.

```
Log Table
| ProductID | Price | Date      |
| 27        | $300  | 02.1.2013 |
| 27        | $400  | 03.1.2013 |
```

This way you can have a nice and neat Products table that is not cluttered with multiples of the same product, and an unobtrusive log table that is easily accessible.

Hope this gives you some guidance on building your site and database.

Answer (score 0):

Add new column for history in 'item' table and each price change append the changed value to this column with a specific format as like date1:price1,date2:price2,....